# Subversion merge history visualisation

Tags: svn, merge, visualization

Are there any utilities out there which can draw pictures of the merge history of a subversion repo - we always commit merges with a (fairly) consistent log message, and it would be handy to be able to automatically extract this info into a single picture that shows what branches occurred when, and what the state of merges is.

I'm just interested in an informational tool, not something to help with actually performing merges.

Answer (score 5):

I use [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/features/) for this; I has a very quick and easy to use revision graph, which can show  svm:mergeinfo as colour coded links and arrows between branches.  It's pretty hard to beat when looking at a good-size source tree

Answer (score 4):

TortoiseSVN can show [revision graph](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-revgraph.html) - visual representation of branching \ merging history and more.

Comment: This is not really correct, I see no visual representation of merges. Also confirmed in http://stackoverflow.com/q/918638.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at some of the visualisation techniques used here, for inspiration if you are developing your own system, some nice ideas.

[RaphaelJS Github Vis](http://raphaeljs.com/github/impact.html)
[Code Swarm](http://vis.cs.ucdavis.edu/~ogawa/codeswarm/)

Probably you know some of this already!

Answer (score 2):

The [svn mergeinfo](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.mergeinfo.html) command provides an ASCII-art graph of the merges between two branches. You can also ask it to give you the revisions already merged, or needing a merge, in list format.

Answer (score -3):

I think Tortoise svn does [**not yet**](http://svn.haxx.se/tsvnusers/archive-2008-05/0149.shtml) support version tree.

So far, Clearcase explorer is the best i've come across.

Comment: Is that for Clearcase only though? I mean, how can it help browse a subversion repository history?

Comment: As i said, i havent come across any tool which shows visualization for Subversion. The screeshot was from Clearcase version tree. Ofcourse it doesnt help subversion. I just posted to show what is available there in clearcase!

Comment: Even though you said in the text that the image is from ClearCase, the large graphic is very misleading and doesn't contribute to the answer.