# How can I get an SVN history of changes that will tell me what I merged with?

Tags: svn, merge

I completely forgot which branch I merged with. I used svn log to view my comments, but these are inadequate and I am curious how I can learn what I automatically merged with.

Thanks.

Comment: Similar [question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56090/subversion-merge-history-visualisation).

Comment: I need a command line solution, not a tool...

Answer (score 1):

Do a propget of `svn:mergeinfo` to get some idea of the merges done.

```
svn propget svn:mergeinfo
```

Comment: Agree. You can look at the svn:mergeinfo property to see what versions were merged into a particular file or directory. The `propget` command should do the job.

Comment: That command prints nothing. Also svn log does not tell me what I merged with.